# iOS 8 update broken iPhone 5 Wi-Fi and landscape keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 5 and just installed the new iOS 8 update, however I am suffering from a couple of problems:

- I can't connect to any Wi-Fi and in Settings I cannot even get the push button to move to turn on Wi-Fi.
- When I start to write a text and turn my phone side ways the screen goes black for several seconds then when it comes back only a few letters on the keyboard will work however most will not. If I tilt my phone to the upright position it works.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: Hi Kim, welcome to the site!  I think you mean WiFi on iOS 8 is broken?  If so, can you edit your question so that others who can possibly fix your problem can find it more easily?

Comment: YFi is a application from a Integrated Design Tools, Inc!